# Form post to multiple action methods based on model value in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In Asp.net MVC, Is it possible to have a form post to two different actions based on model value when clicked on the same button?

Ex. - I want to add a new customer or update an existing customer on click of the same button "Save". Can the form be posted to two different action methods based on the customer's id value.

if the customer id value  = 0 , then post it to "Create" acction method , if the customer id value is already present (not equal to 0), then post the form to "Update" action method?

Is this possible in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 1):

No You cant call multiple action on submit with fairly way,

You need to add hiddenfield for id

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="@model.Id" />
```

When you submit the form the value will be retrieve from model

And check the hidden field value is 0 or not

If 0 than the entity needs to create else it is for update

```
public ActionResult Save(Customer customer){
    if(customer.id > 0){
        // Update Entity
    }
    else{
        // Create Entity
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. There are multiple ways to do it.

**1)** You can conditionally set the form `action` attribute value based on your view model property value.

```
<form method="post" action="@(Model.Id==0?Url.Action("Create","Home")
                                                          :Url.Action("Update","Home"))">
      <input type="text" name="FirstName" />
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**2)** Another option is, you can add html5 `formaction` to your submit button and the value of that attribute could be the url to create or update action method based on your `Id` property value.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home"))
{
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" />
    <button type="submit" 
            formaction="@(Model.Id==0?Url.Action("Create","Home")
                                :Url.Action("Update","Home"))">Save</button>
}
```

When you specify the `formaction` attribute on a submit button, it will overrides the parent form's action attribute value.

**3)** Another option is to hijack the form `submit` event in javascript, prevent the default behavior (stopping the form submit) and then update the form's `action` attribute value to `/create` or `/update` and trigger form `submit` using javascript. You can keep the `Id` property value in a hidden field inside the form and read the value of that and use that to determine what should be the url for the form's action attribute value.

Assuming you have a hidden element for the Id of type `int` property in your page

```
@model YourViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home",FormMethod.Post,new {id="yourFormId"}))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.FirstName)
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    @Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.Id)
}
```

and the javascript to hijack the form submit and update the form's action attribute value would be like

```
$(function () {

    $("#yourFormId").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // stop the normal form submit
        var id=parseInt($("#Id").val());
        var url=$(this).attr("action");
        if(id===0)
        {
           url='/Home/Update'; // Use the Url.Action to be safe to generate this
        }
        // read the data attribute and update the forms action and do a submit
        $(this).closest("form").attr('action', url).submit();
    });
});
```

**4)** Another option is always submitting the form to `Update` or `Create` action and inside that method, based on the the `Id` property value, execute the code for Update or Create as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This for the View case:

```
@mode MyModel
@{
    string action = Model.Id == 0 ? "Create" : "Edit"
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(action, "MyController"))
{
    // if Edit need Id
    if(action == "Edit")
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model=> model.Id)
    }

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model >= model.Name);
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
}
```